# Problem calling one Angular component from another component

Tags: javascript, angular

At work, I have run into a problem using Angular. I have this kind of Angular component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'foo',
templateUrl: 'foo.html'
})
export class FooComponent {
  @Input() data: string;
  content: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.content = this.data;
  }
  setValue(data) {
    this.content = data;
  }
}
```

This is initialized from my main Angular component in a code block such as this:

```
this.components = [FooComponent, BarComponent, BazComponent, QuuxComponent];
```

Now this works so far. But if I try to call the `setValue()` function with `this.components[0].setValue("Hello world!");` I get an error "`this.components[0].setValue is not a function.`"

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very very weird way to work with components in angular.

- You really don't want to break encapsulation by calling methods inside one component from another component.
- I personally haven't seen this kind of component referencing anywhere (and have doubts it is a correct approach).
- There is no reason to duplicate the data property in the content.

You can pass values in the template. Or use a service if you don't have direct access to the template.

Here is a very basic example on how to modify data from the parent using a template and `@Input`.

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  message = "I am a message from the parent";
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<app-child [content]='message'></app-child>
```

*child.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input("content") public content: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

*child.component.html*

```
<p>{{content}}</p>
```

Comment: The idea here was that an event happening in the main component should also trigger a change in `FooComponent`. In a traditional OO programming language, I'd just assign a reference to an object to a variable and call the object's methods through that. I don't know enough about Angular to understand why it uses a different paradigm.
Anyway, I got it to work by creating a new `FooService` which is defined as a singleton and then injected into both components. `FooComponent` lets `FooService` know about itself, and the main component can then call the component through the service.

Comment: I think the approach I described originates from the idea of regular html/xml attributes opposed to any OOP language. The advantage is that you can easily have multiple instances of a child component and see what is going on in your template file. Another advantage is that the data in the parent does not have to be equal to the data in the child when you are not using two-way binding. That said services are a perfectly valid way to deal with state as well.

Comment: You will want to manage the state with methods in your service, not a component. You encapsulate the data in the service. The component should only be concerned with  displaying data originating from the service (in my opinion).